# AMD Geode Optimization References

Tags: optimization, assembly, mmx, amd-processor

I am working on doing some significant optimization of some machine vision code on an embedded AMD Geode LX. I am going as far as to rewrite the computationally intense portions in Assembly, making heavy use of the x86 MMX instructions.

The basic MMX instruction set has many references, but I am looking for specific guides for optimizing for the Geode LX.

The AMD website has a few AMD64 and Athlon optimization guides, but I have had no luck finding any information on the Geode specifically.

I am looking for information on such Geode specific things as pipelining, speed of different instructions, and other speed critical information. Information just on how the Geode works, as well as tips for improving code, would be very helpful.

I am working with an AMD Geode LX 800.

[edit] This website is *exactly* what I'm looking, except it only focuses on AMD Athlon and Opteron processors:
http://www.agner.org/optimize/

Comment: Damn. I was sure I had the hardware reference downloaded somewhere in my home directory of my FitPC, but I can't find it; and AMD has withdrawn the documentation now. I'll keep it in mind to let you know, in case I locate it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

http://support.amd.com/us/Embedded_TechDocs/gx1_ds.pdf

[edit] or this:

http://support.amd.com/us/Embedded_TechDocs/33234H_LX_databook.pdf

Comment: The latter (Geode LX Data Book) should be helpful as a processor overview, which is great. I am looking for a bit more of a guide to optimizing for the Geode, which this doesn't really cover, though it does provide some general information which will be helpful in optimizing.